# Web scaping: how to access the tbody of this table with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In my first try with web scraping with Python I'm trying to extract the content from this webpage:
https://www.sixnationsrugby.com/report/conway-at-the-double-as-ireland-defeat-wales-in-dublin#match-stats.
In particular, I'm trying to take the set of numbers of the table.

I've tried to apply the most common solutions with Pandas, BeautifulSoup but I can't access the tr tag in the tbody.
Can someone indicate me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code I tried:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47IHT.jpg)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table data is not contained at that URL, it is fetched from elsewhere by your web browser.

You can use your web browsers Network Tools search through requests, here we've used the first player in the table.

[image]

Which returns: https://g9u7p6f6.ssl.hwcdn.net/api/custom/statsPlayer/fixture/21IW8573?lang=en_GB as the source of the table data - which is in JSON format.

The URL is assembled from information contained in the html:

```
3556 var STATS_API_VARS = {"base_url":"https:\/\/g9u7p6f6.ssl.hwcdn.net\/api\/"};¬
```

```
2085         data-article-fixguid="21IW8573"¬
```

You can extract the url using string slicing:

```
start = r.text.find('var STATS_API_VARS')
end = r.text.find('}', start) + 1
start = r.text.find('{', start) 

r.text[start:end]
# '{"base_url":"https:\\/\\/g9u7p6f6.ssl.hwcdn.net\\/api\\/"}'
```

Which can be loaded using the `json` module:

```
>>> json.loads(r.text[start:end])['base_url']
'https://g9u7p6f6.ssl.hwcdn.net/api/'
```

The `fixguid` can be extracted with beautifulsoup:

```
>>> soup.find(attrs={'data-article-fixguid': True})['data-article-fixguid']
'21IW8573'
```

Combining these steps you can:

```
...

game_url = 'https://www.sixnationsrugby.com/report/conway-at-the-double-as-ireland-defeat-wales-in-dublin#match-stats'

r = requests.get(game_url)

...

api_url = json.loads(r.text[start:end])['base_url']
stats = 'custom/statsPlayer/fixture/'
fixguid = soup.find(attrs={'data-article-fixguid': True})['data-article-fixguid']

player_stats_table = requests.get(api_url + stats + fixguid).json()
```

An example of loading a subset of the data:

```
pd.json_normalize(
   player_stats_table['data']['playerStats']['playerStatistics']['teamA']
).filter(regex='player.*Name')
```

```
   player.firstName player.lastName
0              Hugo          Keenan
1            Andrew          Conway
2             Garry        Ringrose
3            Bundee             Aki
4              Mack          Hansen
5            Johnny          Sexton
6           Jamison     Gibson-Park
7            Andrew          Porter
8             Ronan        Kelleher
9             Tadhg         Furlong
10            Tadhg          Beirne
11            James            Ryan
12           Caelan           Doris
13             Josh   van der Flier
14             Jack           Conan
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm trying to get through it!